# CSS direction property, actual page language and SEO

Tags: seo, css

I have a menu with a vertical scrollbar in my HTML pages.
This menu is on the left side of the HTML pages.
In order to have the `scrollbar` `on the left side` of the menu, I used a trick I found on the Internet: I added the CSS property `direction: rtl;`

The `page language` (culture) is either French or English.
I am wondering if (Google) search engine bots can get confused because they have contradictory information concerning the culture of the website and if it can impact SEO negatively.
The `direction` property is obviously taken into account for rendering the page but it is also taken into account by (Google) search engine bots for referencing pages?

Answer (score 0):

I think you set property direction: rtl for that menu division [Block] only. Google bots wont have any confusion by that.